# Gettiing last items using linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list that get from database using entity framework.

```
var list = context.Items;
```

list result is like this.

```
var list = new List<Item>{
    new Item { id=1, operation="write", date="23.03.2018 08:25:45" },
    new Item { id=1, operation="read", date="23.03.2018 09:40:15" },
    new Item { id=1, operation="read", date="23.03.2018 10:15:17" },
    new Item { id=1, operation="read", date="23.03.2018 11:46:39" }
}
```

I want to minify this list by operation and last date.

```
var min = new List<Item>{
    new Item { id=1, operation="write", date="23.03.2018 08:25:45" },
    new Item { id=1, operation="read", date="23.03.2018 11:46:39" }
}
```

I am getting last '`write`' operation and last '`read`' item.

Comment: do you need only last items from collection?

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Just group by with operation and select the last date in each group.

```
var lastItems = list.GroupBy(p => p.operation).Select(grp => new
        {
            grp.Key,
            lastOperation = grp.OrderByDescending(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.date)).First()
        }).Select(p=> p.lastOperation);
```

However, if your date field contains different time formats it may fail to convert to DateTime.

And you need to make sure to convert date field to DateTime otherwise you may get different ordering by string.

Edit: The following does the same thing with less typing:

```
var lastItems = list.GroupBy(p => p.operation).Select(grp => 
            grp.OrderByDescending(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.date)).First());
```

Comment: I think it is reasonable to use `First` and not `FirstOrDefault` for these as you know every `grp` is going to contain at least one item, or it wouldn't have been created.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the concept of numbering the rows based on the date, and then filtering them. Something like:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.operation)
               .SelectMany(g =>
                   g.OrderByDescending(i => i.date).Select((j, i) => new { j.id, j.operation,j.date, rn = i + 1 })
               );

var data = groups.Where(i => i.rn == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need distinct value form the list and then you need to get first item with latest date

```
List<Item> list = context.Items
                  .GroupBy(a => a.operation)
                  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.date)).First())
                  .ToList();
```

you need to perform `group by on operation`  once its done you should take first item from each group but to take latest by date you need to perform descending on date which will make latest date record first recoed and than you just need to apply first function on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the help of following code

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.operation)
                 .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => Convert.ToDateTime(y.date)).FirstOrDefault())
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Max` is (much) faster than sorting, use `Max`. Unfortunately your `date` field is not a `DateTime`, so conversion is needed. I did the conversion first so I wouldn't have to do it twice when filtering. I also didn't assume there would be only one most recent `date` per operation, if you need only you could add a `First`. I preserved and returned the original `Item` at the end.

```
var min = from item in list
          select new { item, date = DateTime.Parse(item.date) } into newitem
          group newitem by newitem.item.operation into itemgroup
          let maxdate = itemgroup.Max(i => i.date)
          from item in itemgroup
          where item.date == maxdate
          select item.item;
```

Note: It is possible that .Net Core handles the case of `OrderBy.First` specially without sorting.